# Unable to resolve drawable fab_icon android

Tags: android, drawable, floating-action-button

In my application I am using `com.android.support:design:25.0.0` to get `FloatingActionButton` but when ever i set Icon for it

```
app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_done"
```

I'm getting an error

`Cannot Resolve symbol @drawable/ic_done`

I have tried out other icons but none of them is working?

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_cust"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_nxt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_done"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Gradle Dependecies:**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Edit:**

Ive also tried replacing fab_icon with android:src but none of it working.
[image]

Comment: can you post your xml  code

Comment: change `com.android.support:design:25.0.0` to `com.android.support:design:24.2.1` and try it

Comment: @sasikumar I ve updated the question with XML. actually its not geting drawable with particular names. If Im not wrong they are provided by design support lib. but unable to access them.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `src` instead of icon. Follow code.

```
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_done"
```